# Xamarin Android: Hide botton navigation view and show when a recyclerview row is selected

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Hello Everyone my name is Taniguchi and i ve inserted in my solution a recyclerview and a botton navigation view.

i Wonder how to hide the botton navigation view when the aplication is started and show the botton navigation view when i select a item on my recyclerview.

My Click Listener:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mSubject;
        public TextView mMessage;
        public CheckBox cbx;
        public BottomNavigationView bottomBar;
        public int count = 0;
        private Action<object, View.LongClickEventArgs, int> onLongClick;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            mName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            mSubject = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            mMessage = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            cbx = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
            bottomBar = itemView.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationView);
        }

    }
```

My Recycler View Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
    {
        private View view;
        private Boolean isSelected = false;

        public Boolean IsSelected()
        {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
        {
            isSelected = selected;
        }
        private Activity mActivity;
        private MyActionMode mActionMode;
        private List<Email> mEmails;
        private Context context;
        private ActionMode mode;
        private BottomNavigationView bottonbar;
        public bool count = false;
        public int CountAuxiliar = 0;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public View mMainView { get; set; }
            public TextView mName { get; set; }
            public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
            public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

            public MyView(View view) : base(view)
            {
                mMainView = view;
            }

        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mEmails.Count; }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
            return vh;
        }
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {  
            RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            myHolder.bottomBar.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
            myHolder.cbx.Checked = mEmails[position].IsSelected();
            myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
            myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
            myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;
            myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);
        }
        public RecyclerViewHolder myHolder;

        void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
        {
            if (CountAuxiliar > 0 && mode != null)
            {
                int position = (int)v.Tag;
                mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
                v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
                v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
                v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationView).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
                if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
                {
                    CountAuxiliar++;
                }
                else
                {
                    CountAuxiliar--;
                }
                mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
                Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + CountAuxiliar + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            if (CountAuxiliar < 1 && count == true)
            {
                mode.Finish();
            }
        }

        public bool OnLongClick(View v)
        {

            if (CountAuxiliar < 1)
            {
                CountAuxiliar = 1;
                count = true;
                int position = (int)v.Tag;
                mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
                v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
                v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
                v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottomNavigationView).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity, this, position);
                mode = mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
                mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionado";
                count = true;

                Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position].IsSelected() + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In the Line:

```
myHolder.bottomBar.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
```

Is showing the error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You are taking `bottomBar` from the wrong view I think. In the click you are taking view from `myHolder.ItemView` and in `OnBindViewHolder` you are taking it directly from `holder`, Not sure which is the correct one without seeing your holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquoti Wonder how to hide the botton navigation view when the aplication is started and show the botton navigation view when i select a item on my recyclerview.e

I think you can use Contextual Action Bar in RecyclerView, firstly,create simple menu in Resource/Menu/bottom_bar_menu, then create a class(MyActionMode) implements ActionMode.ICallBack. More detailed info, you can take a look this demo.

https://github.com/elvisxia/RecyclerViewer

You can long click Recyclerview item to display Contextual Action Bar.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much  Cherry Bu, this way Works better